# Referencing Jpanel in subclass

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java.  We're starting to use it at my job, but I'm trying to learn as much as I can on my own to get a head start before they start any formal training.

I've been reading through different books on Java, playing around with the example programs and sometimes making improvements on them.  I've been playing around with an amortization program I found in one of the books.  The example did calculations based on some hard-coded values in the program, so I broke off the part that does the calculations into a separate class, and set up a main class that accepts input values.  I used Springlayout for this.

Now I'm trying to learn about extending classes.  Basically, I want to add some new fields to the main class, but I keep getting an error in Eclipse when I try to specify the position of the new field.  I'm able to reference the fields from the superclass, but I can't figure out how to reference anything having to do with the Jpanel.

Editing my original post as requested.  Hopefully this makes it more clear...

I followed the link with the Springlayout examples.  I used the second one, listed as SpringDemo2:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

package layout;

import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Container;

public class SpringDemo2 {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpringDemo2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(layout);

        //Create and add the components.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label: ");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Text field", 15);
        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(textField);

        //Adjust constraints for the label so it's at (5,5).
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, label,
                             5,
                             SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, label,
                             5,
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);

        //Adjust constraints for the text field so it's at
        //(<label's right edge> + 5, 5).
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textField,
                             5,
                             SpringLayout.EAST, label);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textField,
                             5,
                             SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It simply shows a text box with a label.  I tried to post a picture of it but apparently I can't do that just yet.  I'm trying to extend this class into a new class, adding a text box and label below the original one.  This is what I put together:

```
package layout;

import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class SpringDemo2a extends SpringDemo2 {

    @Override
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2: ");
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("Text field 2", 15);
        contentPane.add(label2);
        contentPane.add(textField2);

        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, label2,
                105,
                SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, label2,
                105,
                SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);

        //Adjust constraints for the text field so it's at
        //(<label's right edge> + 5, 5).
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textField2,
                105,
                SpringLayout.EAST, label2);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textField2,
                105,
                SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);

    }
}
```

It's giving me errors where I reference contentPane and layout.  I thought I needed an @Override statement, but it's giving me an error on that too.

Comment: *I'm new to Java.* Start by reading and downloading the working examples from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The demo code will show you how to better structure your code so you don't have layout problems. Also, the `SpringLayout` is one of the more complicated layout managers. You should master the other basic layout managers first before attempting the SpringLayout. Also post a proper [mre] when asking a question. We can't tell the context of how all those random lines of code are used.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the full source code of your classes.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.